# SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload file to AWS s3 bucket. I'm continuously getting this exception "SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset".

I'm trying to upload by inputstream

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred))
                .build();
        try {

            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentLength(bytesArray.length);
            metadata.setContentType("text/csv");
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(appConfig.getBucketName(), fileName, inStream, metadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        }
    ----
```

Below is the exception in detail. What could be the reason? My S3 bucket has IAM user with S3 full access policy. Is this issue related to network or any other settings?

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1136)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1082)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
-------
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142
```

Comment: it might be, you're behind proxy?

Comment: Yes @Rodel, I found it is occurring due to firewall.  SSL hand shake is failing due to firewall.

Comment: not exactly same, but I was having issue because the bucket was on global, but I was passing on `us-east-1`

Answer (score 2):

I found it is occurring due to the firewall. If you set logging.level.com.amazonaws at DEBUG then it will show SSL handshake failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application behind a proxy, this may happens. You can set the proxy as,

```
public static void setProxy() {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<http-proxy-url>");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<port>");

        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "<https-proxy-url>");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "<port>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, disabling the `AWS Toolkit plugin` works.